# Rails - Set ID to 1 for each new association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is a more theoretical question, i have been thinking about this kind of "issue" for a longer period of time and couldn't find any real answer to that.

Lets start with this simple setup:

```
project.rb

has_many :tasks
```

and

```
task.rb

belongs_to :project
```

Now each project can have a task.

Imagine a completely fresh DB:

If i create a new **project(1)** and 5 tasks for this project afterwards, the task 1-5 will be associated with project 1, right?

Now if i create another **project(2)** and create for this project 5 new tasks, the id will start with 6 and go up to 11.

The question is: Is it possible that the ID of the tasks for the **second project** starts again at 1 even though there is already the task record 1-5 for project 1? Basically what i want is that each project has kind of "isolated" tasks, so that every task starts again at the id of 1 for each project. This way, it would be much more organized to find for example task 23 for project 2, and task 23 for project 1 simply by searching the id.

Does that make sense?

**Please let me know if something is not clear.**

Thanks in advance everyone in advance as always!

Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a difference between DB ID and the ID used for routing and display.

For instance,

you can use a separate field called, `displayed_id` and put whatever number you want there.
You can set a constraint on it to be unique with respect to your project_id.
That said, you can find a task by always going for `project.tasks.find_by(displayed_id: params[:id])`

Comment: Thanks for your input. Thats sounds like a great idea. I upvoted it already, but have to test it out later! I also thought about a has_many :through association that has a connection to the task itself. But your idea sounds a lot less of a hassle than creating join table.